# how to convert user input to string in Excel-DNA

Tags: excel-dna

Is it possible to call function without including " in parameter for a string param in Excel-DNA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Excel interprets the formula before calling the [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) add-in, and if you don't have the quotes Excel will try to interpret the parameter as a name (names include ranges, names added in the Name Manager etc).

Why is this an issue for you - it is consistent with how Excel works otherwise?

Comment: Thanks for the reply .This is required since I am developing an excel add in for elastic search and user may happy to type for example getContent(africa,18-07-2012,04-09-2012)rather than
getContent("africa","18-07-2012 00:00:00","04-09-2012 09:53:26") right?