# Excel-dna getting percentage values

Tags: excel-dna

I ran into a problem when trying to get percentage values from excel using ExcelReference.getValues(). For 300% it comes back as 3.0 and so on.

Is there any way to distinguish if the value was percentage and formatted to number?

The problem is similar to this one [how to convert user input to string in Excel-DNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596368/how-to-convert-user-input-to-string-in-excel-dna) although it's more formatting problem than calculating formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the C API `GET.CELL` information function to get the formatted value of the cell, using info type 53. It returns: "Contents of the cell as it is currently displayed, as text, including any additional numbers or symbols resulting from the cell's formatting."

```
object contents = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfGetCell, 53, theReference);
```

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot